# Typescript - Import modules that only extend globals

Tags: module, typescript, external, require, amd

In a JS module which needs bootstrap, I currently write

```
define(["dep1", "dep2", "bootstrap"], function(dep1, dep2) { });
```

That is: NO variable for the bootstrap dependency, as that module only extends the global JQuery object without exporting anything.

How can I achieve the same behavior in Typescript? I tried

```
import dep1 = require("dep1");
import dep2 = require("dep2");
import bs = require("bootstrap");
```

but the generated JS is like

```
define(["require", "exports", "dep1", "dep2"], function($, exports, dep1, dep2) { });
```

and the bootstrap module is NOT loaded.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The solution (requires Typescript 1.5+):

before

```
import $ = require("jquery");
```

add

```
///<amd-dependency path="bootstrap"/>
```

The path is either the relative path to the file, or the require path you define in require.config({ paths: ... })
This is because the content of the path attribute in this tag will be literally pasted in the define statement in the generated js file!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import = "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score -1):

it happens because the TypeScript compiler can`t find module with name `bootstrap`, that is why this module is omitted.

Try to integrate in you project [bootstrap.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts). Or declare own module with name bootstrap, and import it.

[This example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=import%20dep1%20%3D%20require(%22dep1%22)%3B%0D%0Aimport%20dep2%20%3D%20require(%22dep2%22)%3B%0D%0Aimport%20bs%20%3D%20require(%22bootstrap%22)%3B) shows that undeclared modules has been omitted

### Update

I have just discovered [bootstrap.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts#L118) and found that it support `AMD` module and can be used in `import`

### See also

1. [Using d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd#tsddts)